# Handlebars block helper "if" doesn't work

Tags: handlebars.js

I'm making a movie search based on data I'm getting from rotten tomatoes api. I'm using handlebars.js. So far I've got this template and it works just fine.

```
    <div class="info">
        <h3>{{title}}</h3>
        <span> Year: {{year}} </span>
        <span> Studio:{{studio}} </span> 
        <span> Synopsis:{{synopsis}} <span>
    </div>
```

However, some of of movies don't have a studio provided so I'd like to make that in this case no "Studio:" would be printed. This is my code to do so:

```
   {{#if studio}}
     <span> Studio:{{studio}} </span> 
   {{/if}}
```

I've copied it from example provided on handebars.js page. Still it doesn't work. Could anyone explain me what I'm missing? I suppose there is no need to use Handlebars.registerHelper since I'm using this simple if statement. Or is it?

Comment: Why aren't you using `#unless` instead? It's basically `!#if` which is what you need by the looks of things

Comment: Still it doesn't work, no <span> Studio:{{studio}} </span> is printed.

Answer (score 0):

see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BHrmC/109/). You should not have any issue with that.

From [documentation](http://handlebarsjs.com/).

> You can use the if helper to conditionally render a block. If its
>   argument  returns **false, undefined, null, "" or []** (a "falsy" value),
>   Handlebars will not  render the block.

So check your 'studio' value.

Code that i have fiddled.

**HTML:**

```
<p>{{name1}}</p> 
{{#if name2}}
   <p>{{name2}}</p>    
{{/if}}
<p>End</p>
```

**js:**

```
this.$el.html(temp({name1: 'stack'}));
```